# How to sum up all numbers in an array

Tags: groovy

I have an array which outputs the following:

```
charges = [5.00, 26.00, 8.00, 4.00, 4.00, -8.00, 54.00, 52.48]
```

When I try to perform a sum using this:

```
charges.sum()
```

It gives me:

```
5.0026.008.004.004.00-8.0054.0052.48
```

I am assuming I need to convert it from a string to a float so I did:

```
Float.valueOf((String) charges.sum())
```

and it gives me an error which states 'multiple points'.

My question is how do I add all of these figures up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list is actually of strings, you can quickly do the conversion with `sum()`'s closure form.

```
charges.sum { it.toBigDecimal() }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what your list has in it, it seems like the entries in your list are actually strings (since sum concatenates them), or something that prints a string value (has a toString method that returns a string showing the value so you think it is numeric even though it isn’t) . They are definitely not numeric, so convert each of them to a numeric type before summing:

```
charges.collect { new BigDecimal(it.toString()) }.sum()
```

(What your code was doing was concatenating the string values together, then converting that to a numeric type.)

Answer (score -2):

You must delete the cast (String)

```
Float.valueOf(charges.sum())
```